# SSH key not being added to ssh-agent automatically

Tags: keychain, ssh, git

OS version is Ventura 13.2

I generated an SSH key to authenticate git operations with GitHub according to [their guide](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent). Followed the steps:

1. `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my identifier"` (Without passphrase. Saved to `~/.ssh/github`)
2. `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
3. `touch ~/.ssh/config`
4. Added this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *.github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

5. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/github`

When testing the connection with `ssh -T git@github.com` it is successful, but after rebooting, closing the terminal, restarting vscode, etc, I have to manually re-add the SSH key using `ssh-add` again; otherwise I'm met with the error: `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

I expect the key to be added to the SSH agent automatically so that I may perform git operations without having to manually add the key to the SSH agent every time. It used to work before on my old MBP. How can I solve this?

Comment: When you "re-add the SSH key" are you just doing step #5, or are you also doing some of the others (esp step #2?)

Answer (score 1):

Your `~/.ssh/config` file has a slight error in the hostname line.

> ```
> Host *.github.com
>   AddKeysToAgent yes
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
> ```

`*.github.com` will only match *subdomains* of github.com.  Your `ssh -T git@github.com` is going directly to the main domain `github.com` which does *not* match `*.github.com`

Change that first line to `Host github.com` and you should be good.

PS - Welcome to **Ask**Different!